# Flutter - Applying Background Gradient to Scrollable View

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there a way to apply a full background gradient to a scrollable view (such as ListView or SingleChildScrollView) in Flutter? I've tried various methods, such as applying gradient to Scaffold or wrapping Scaffold in Container, but the gradient seems to just scroll with the content instead of applying to the full scrollable height.

Example: [DartPad example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/331aece1019372dd2e82a3a509cd2aff)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient:LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            colors: [Colors.green, Colors.orange],
            stops: [0, 1],
          ),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 500,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Text('$index'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its working fine ! Tested with dartpad !

Accept the answer if it works !

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [Colors.green, Colors.orange],
                    stops: [0, 1],
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: List.generate(500, (ind) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('$ind'),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the gradient to scroll. However, if you don't mind setting the children of the ListView to a fixed height, there is a workaround!

1. Save your gradient as an image
2. Create a Stateful Widget, our `ListView` with gradient background will go in here.
3. Put the image we just created in a fixed height `Container`, with the image as a background image; the fixed height is the total height of the `ListView`.
4. Wrap the `Container` with a SingleChildScrollView. Create a new `ScrollController` for this.
5. Wrap the `ListView` and the `Container` in a `Stack`. Also create a new controller for the `ListView`.
6. In the initState method of our custom Widget, we'll set the controller for the bg to track the movement of the ListView.

Our code will look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: MyListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListViewState createState() => _MyListViewState();
}

class _MyListViewState extends State<MyListView> {
  final ScrollController listViewController = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController backgroundController = ScrollController();
  final int itemCount = 500;
  final double itemHeight = 20.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    listViewController.addListener(() {
      backgroundController.jumpTo(listViewController.offset);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        // Our gradient background
        SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: backgroundController,
          child: Container(
            height: itemCount * itemHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/gradient.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        ListView.builder(
          controller: listViewController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) => SizedBox(
            height: itemHeight,
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    listViewController.dispose();
    backgroundController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sven, your solution works well (+1). You don't really need the background image: just use the original BoxDecoration provided by @NotoriousV2 and everything works just fine.